# addition without using + operator

Tags: java

Can anybody explain how this function works?

```
public int TestAdd(int a,int b) {

        if(a <1)return b;       
        return(TestAdd((a&b)<<1,a^b));      
    }
```

Comment: Just take two (small) example numbers and walk through the algorithm. If you look at the binary representations of the numbers as you go a along it should become obvious.

Comment: What exactly did you want?  What we think the returned value will be or how the method actually works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding two matching set binary digits is equivalent to setting the next bit up: 1+1=2, and so on. So the function does that for all matching bits, then carries the unmatched ones over to another round. When no unmatched ones remain, it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can obviously test to see that it does indeed add two numbers, I assume you aren't understanding what those symbols are doing.  Java's operators are described here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

And you can easily look up the definitions of "logical AND" and "bitwise exclusive OR" and how they apply to ints.

Answer (score 0):

Here we using the concept of recursion, this function call itself as values- 
 1 bit left shift of binary(Due to carry while adding) addition of numbers and xor of numbers until the a become <1.
Thus it returns the addition of numbers.
You can debug the function by taking some values for better understanding.